# How to keep user logged in when migrating from cordova to react native

Tags: reactjs, cordova, react-native, meteor

I have a cordova app on the App Store and Google Play store. I am preparing a major update to the app by changing the framework to React Native. However, when the user updates the app they lose all login info and they are logged out from the app after the update. How can I persist the user from cordova to react native?

Comment: i'm having the same issue would love a solution, i found this https://github.com/wootwoot1234/react-native-webkit-localstorage-reader.

but doesnt look like it works with later react-native versions

Comment: Which service did you use before to login? Password, facebook, twitter, google, etc.?

Comment: We just used our own api using username/password and stored auth data in the localStorage now when we use AsyncStorage we cannot access the old data that was in localStorage in the cordova app

Comment: @Jankapunkt auth with email and password

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a working solution to this problem?

Comment: @Unstableair  Unfortunately I couldn't find a graceful way to let user continue without an interruption. However, I have created a webview inside the react native app that users can log in to my old webapp and from that webview, I have send logged in users info to app via ```onMessage={event => {
      alert('MESSAGE >>>>' + event.nativeEvent.data);
    }}```

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem, where I needed to preserve information to keep the user logged in the migration process, the bookstores I used to carry out the process were these, I know it's an old question, but if anyone faces the same problem, you can follow this one solution.

It consists of installing a plugin in the Cordova app, to prepare the information so that the React update can be retrieved using another specific library, that is, it will be necessary to launch a last Cordova update in the store, to later launch in React.

React Native library:

https://github.com/kevinresol/react-native-default-preference

Cordova plugin:

https://github.com/adriano-di-giovanni/cordova-plugin-shared-preferences

To save information via cordova:

```
var sharedPreferences = window.plugins.SharedPreferences.getInstance('settings');
sharedPreferences.put('foo', 'bar', function () { }, function () { });
```

To retrieve information in react native:

```
await DefaultPreference.setName('settings');
DefaultPreference.get('foo').then(value => console.log(value) /*print bar*/ );
```

It's a clumsy solution, but it was the only one I found and it worked for me, this method can only handle string information, so if I need to save something more complex, I recommend using JSON.stringify/JSON.parse, and depending on the information saved, I recommend clean up after recovering what you need:

```
DefaultPreference.clear("foo");
```

Remembering that you must ensure that the React application launched for Android must have the same package/signature key as the Cordova version, for this solution to work, otherwise the information cannot be retrieved.

For further questions I recommend reading the documentation of both repositories.